# Rails 4.0.8 Bundle Install keeps poiting to the wrong Ruby version

Tags: rvm, homebrew

I'm working through the Railstutorial with Rails 4.0.8. and Ruby 2.1.2. Recently Bundle Install, Rails Console and Rails Server seem to ALWAYS choose the alternate version of Ruby from whichever is specify in my Gemfile. When I enter ruby -v it also always suggests the OTHER version.
Is this a bash_profile problem and how can I set it to permanently leave the internal OS X Ruby (v2.0.0) alone and just use v 2.1.2 where all my gems are installed?

I'm using rvm and Homebrew... I suspect both may be adding to the confusion...

Any helpful tips?

First...

micanansmbp:sample_app micanan$ rails console
Your Ruby version is 2.1.2, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

Then...

micanansmbp:sample_app micanan$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Finally...

micanansmbp:sample_app micanan$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
micanansmbp:sample_app micanan$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
micanansmbp:sample_app micanan$